# Create a View Showing Related Tax Term Reference Terms

Tags: views, entities

Hello I have a vocab named 'categories'. I also have a vocab called 'tags'. I have added a term reference field (categories) to tags vocab so as i can relate tags to categories. Previously on D6 i would have the same vocab for both but with D7's new fieldable taxonomy i have to give this a go.

I am trying to create a view (block or views pane) that will display on my Categories term page. The view will contain the tags that are 'related' (have the category field added to them) on display. I am making this sound harder than it is is.

Term (tag vocab) 'Web Design' with term Reference (category vocab) 'Tech'. when i visit 'Tech' i see a view in the sidebar displaying 'web design'.

Can anyone give me any pointers in creating this View? I think I am using the wrong relationship possibly. I have three options. The Optional field is my category field:

> Taxonomy term: Optional (field_optional) This is an alias of Field:
>   Optional (field_optional).
>
> Taxonomy term: Content using Optional Relate each Content with a
>   Optional set to the term.
>
> Taxonomy term: Taxonomy term using Optional Relate each Taxonomy term
>   with a Optional set to the term.

I think if I at least knew the right one to use it might help me accomplish my task. thanks

Comment: so really i need a term view with a contextual filter based on my category (optional) vocab. Then i will need a relation to my TAGS vocab. Then i will display term and use the TAG relationshipo. i think

Comment: bah it doesnt let me use a relationshio the way im doing it. ill leave it for now and hope that someone might be able to help.

Comment: ive asked the same question here on drupal .org. http://drupal.org/node/1975580 hopefully will be able to answer myself soon (dont hold your breath though)